# Systemd config file in docker entrypoint: Error: File contains no section headers

Tags: bash, docker, ubuntu

I am new to Docker and I am having some problems with it that I have not been able to solve. I have two docker container running, one is a MySQL server and the other one is a web app. The entry point script has this command at the end:

```
# Start supervisord
echo "Starting supervisord"
cd /
exec /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
```

When the script runs I get the following error:

```
misp_web | Starting supervisord
misp_db | [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 5.7.26-1.1.11
misp_db | [Entrypoint] Starting MySQL 5.7.26-1.1.11
misp_web | Error: File contains no section headers.
misp_web | file: /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf, line: 1
misp_web | 'nodaemon = true &\n'
misp_web | For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
```

I'd be very grateful if someone could guide me to the right solution as I have been trying to solve this for a while without any success.

Answer (score 0):

I do use this configuration to start the supervisor service in docker container. It contains also laravel commands

```
#!/bin/bash
service supervisor stop
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
sleep 1
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
supervisorctl start laravel-worker:*

# exit 0
```